# How to Unmute Background Video

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a theme that has a background video however i would like to unmute the sound. I tried editing the js and css file but no luck. can anyone help me locate the code weburl is http://modelveenna.com/veenna-garbani-video-intro/

Comment: You can handle it using `volume` property of the element like: `audioElement.volume` OR `audioElement.muted = false` if `audioElement.mute = true`

Comment: @RayonDabre don't believe that'll work as it's a YouTube video.

Comment: @Harangue, Where did OP mention that ?

Comment: @RayonDabre If you inspect the video of the link they have in the question....

Comment: the wordpress theme uses YTPlayer.js i have set volume to 100% but its not working. When i use inspect element something is overriding it class="player video-container mb_YTVPlayer isMuted" and I am not an expert so i dont no where to look for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're creating the element that YTPlayer.js is acting on, you have to set the `data-property` correctly with the options you want.

Currently you have

```
data-property="{videoURL:'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLels6kOdDc',containment:'#fixed_video',autoPlay:true, showControls:false, mute:true, startAt:0, opacity:1}"
```

I think you want to remove `mute: true` from that, i.e.

```
data-property="{videoURL:'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLels6kOdDc',containment:'#fixed_video',autoPlay:true, showControls:false, startAt:0, opacity:1}"
```

Comment: Where do I edit this, Because the js file I am editing mute is set as false

Comment: @MoeHabib this is an HTML property of your #P2 element.

Comment: Thank You @Harangue my problem is solved :) I was looking in the wrong file this whole time

Comment: @MoeHabib You're welcome! Consider marking this question as answered if you feel that my answer was helpful to solving your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

### HTML5 Video:

It depends how you set up your video, but...

```
document.getElementById('videoId').muted=false;
```

Works if you applied the `muted` attribute to the video, where `videoId` is the id of the video you would like to unmute. Example code:

```
<video id="videoId" muted src="/media/example.mp4">No HTML5 Video Support!</video>
```

**OR:**

`document.getElementById('videoId').volume=1;`

Similar, but instead of unmuting simply sets the volume to 1 (`100%`, as the volume ranges in floating point numbers between `0` and `1`. `10%` volume would be `0.1`, for example).

Note that to use this method, you need to set the volume of the video to `0` on page load, as there is no `volume` attribute for HTML5 video.

### Youtube Video:

```
player.unMute();
```

Where `player` is the object returned when you made the video. Youtube provides a lot of basic functions such as `unMute()` with their video API.

Note that this function is avaliable in both the deprecated JS API and the recommended iFrame API, so it should just work.

For more information, see https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference.

Answer (score -1):

Check with video tag attribute `muted`.